# Issue with '/' in String in JAVA

Tags: java, string

for example  "**D:\Runnable-jar\test//**" when I am assigning this value in JAVA String, its treating the '\test' as "TAB est"

That resulting into "**D:\Runnable-jar est//**"

How to detect **'\'** and keep it as it is ?

Comment: use \\test, \t is an escape character for tab.

Comment: `System.out.println( "D:\\Runnable-jar\\test//");`

Comment: Don't use backslashes in Java filenames, `/` works just fine, on all platforms.